# Count only the top cells of a multi dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array as following.

What I want is to just count the top cells of this array; as in 0,1,2,3,4 and 5. So for this array I should have a count of 6.

How can I achieve that?

I tried

`count(array)` and `sizeof(array)`, but it gives a large number.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [2011-11-18 00:00:00] => C
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [2011-11-18 00:00:00] => I
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [2011-11-18 00:00:00] => S
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [2011-11-22 00:00:00] => C
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [2011-11-22 00:00:00] => S
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [2011-11-22 00:00:00] => C
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [2011-11-22 00:00:00] => S
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [2011-11-22 00:00:00] => C
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [2011-11-22 00:00:00] => S
                )

        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [2011-11-22 00:00:00] => C
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [2011-11-22 00:00:00] => S
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [2011-11-22 00:00:00] => C
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [2011-11-22 00:00:00] => S
                )

        )
)
```

Comment: Have you tried `count($array, 0)` ? The second parameter specifies whether count should work or not with multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: where's the codes? `count($array)` should have yielded 6

Comment: i didn't get any problem.It works well count($array);

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try:

```
count(array_column($array , 0));
```

You can read further [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

This is available in >= PHP 5

Comment: No explanation or description provided. Seems like more of a comment. Why should this work when count() allegedly didn't?

Comment: maybe useful for those of us on earlier versions: [Provides functionality for array_column() to projects using PHP earlier than version 5.5](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column).